# Flutter redux update the specific state variable without affecting other variable

Tags: flutter, dart, redux-thunk, flutter-redux

I have a state like this

```
class NameState{
    List name;
    dynamic title;
    NameState({this.title, this.name});
}
```

Action

```
class NameAction{
   List  showAction;
   NameAction(this.showAction);

}
```

reducer like this

```
NameState reducer(NameState state, dynamic action) {

 if (action is NameAction) {
  return NameState(
    name: []..addAll(action.showAction)
  );
}

 return state;

}
```

and initial state is defined like this 
`initialState: new NameState(title: 'this is title', name: []), middleware: [thunkMiddleware]);`

Here is the main problem,

you can see I have given a static string to title variable. It works fine and visible in all pages.

But as soon as reducer is called this title gets a value of null. I don't want to pass any value to title. It should be as it is with it's own value. 
I was updating only the name list.

In javascript state management, we can update any variable we want without affecting other variables in the state. How can I do it in flutter redux?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass all the variables of the current state when returning a new state.

```
NameState reducer(NameState state, dynamic action) {
  if (action is NameAction) {
    return NameState(
      name: []..addAll(action.showAction),
      title: state.title,
    );
  }

  return state;
}
```

Comment: it gives this error when using rebuild 

```The method 'rebuild' isn't defined for the class 'NameState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'rebuild'.```

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I didn't realise that you did not use build runner implementation. I've updated my solution.